# Can't retrieve data from matched * group in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper regex.

Here is some sample code:

```
@Test
public void testFindEasyNaked() {
    System.out.println("Naked_find");
    String arg = "hi mom <us-patent-grant seq=\"002\" image=\"D000001\" >foo<name>Fred</name></us-patent-grant> extra stuff";
    String nakedPat = "<(us-patent-grant)((\\s*[\\S&&[^>]])*)*\\s*>(.+?)</\\1>";
    System.out.println(nakedPat);

    Pattern naked = Pattern.compile(nakedPat, Pattern.MULTILINE + Pattern.DOTALL );
    Matcher m = naked.matcher(arg);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("found naked");
        for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", i, m.group(i));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("can't find naked either");
    }
    System.out.flush();
}
```

My regex matches the string, but I am not able to pull the repeated pattern.
What I want is to have

```
   seq=\"002\" image=\"D000001\"
```

pulled out as a group. Here is what the program shows when I execute it.

```
Naked_find
<(us-patent-grant)((\s*[\S&&[^>]])*)*\s*>(.+?)</\1>
found naked
0: <us-patent-grant seq="002" image="D000001" >foo<name>Fred</name></us-patent-grant>
1: us-patent-grant
2: 
3: "
4: foo<name>Fred</name>
```

The group #4 is fine, but where is the data for #2 and #3, and why is there a double quote in #3?

Thanks
Pat

Comment: Regexing XML has all kinds of problems. Why not use a parser?

Comment: Mostly because the ones that I've looked at are opaque. Which do you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Even if using an XML parser would be sound, I think I can explain the error in your regular expression:

```
String nakedPat = "<(us-patent-grant)((\\s*[\\S&&[^>]])*)*\\s*>(.+?)</\\1>";
```

You try to match the parameters in the part `((\\s*[\\S&&[^>]])*)*`. Look at your innermost group: you have `\s*` ("one or more space") followed by `\\S&&[^>]` ("one non-space which is not `>`). It means that in your group, you will either have from zero to some spaces followed by a *single* non-space character.

So this will match any non-space character between "us-patent-grant" and `>`. And every time the regular expression engine will match it, it will *assign* the value to the group 3. It means the group previously matched are lost. That's why you have the last character of the tag, that is `"`.

You can improve it a bit by adding a `+` after `[\\S&&[^>]]`, so it will match at least a complete sequence of non-spaces, but you would only obtain the last tag attribute in your group. You should instead use a better and simpler way:

Your goal being to pull out `seq="002" image="D000001"` in a group, what you should do is simply to match the sequence of every characters which are not `>` after "us-patent-grant":

```
"<(us-patent-grant)\\s*([^>]*)\\s*>(.+?)</\\1>"
```

This way, you have the following values in your groups:

```
Group 1: us-patent-grant
Group 2: seq=\"002\" image=\"D000001\"
Group 3: foo<name>Fred</name>
```

Here is the test on Regexplanet: http://fiddle.re/ezfd6